# Clone object's properties by reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pass-by-reference

My Data Object:

```
var data = {
  foo: {
    bar: 42
  },
  baz: true,
  x: 1,
  y: 2
};
```

Now I'd like like to send this object as JSON String. **But** before sending, I'd like to modify my object **and** still keeping the original one.

```
var json = data;
json.foo = json.foo.bar;
json.id = json.baz;
delete json.baz;
```

Of course this will modify my `data` object, too.

Is it possible to create a second object with the same structure as the first one, which allows to rename / delete some properties **without** changing the first object?

I know I could do this:

```
var json = {
  foo: data.foo.bar,
  id: data.baz,
  x: data.x,
  y: data.y
};
```

But imagine the `data` object contains 50 properties and I only want to change two of them.

And I don't want to use `jQuery.copy` or `angular.copy` because of performance reasons (they create **real** copies - that shouldn't be necessary).

Maybe there's something like this ?

```
var json = {
  foo: data.foo.bar,
  id: data.baz
};
json = merge(json, data);
delete json.baz;
```

Thank you! `:)`

Comment: no, you need to serialize a whole object. and you can't change a clone  without affecting the orig. therefore, you need a whole new object, or try your luck with regexp on the output string. or i guess you can mod, serialize, and revert, all on the same object.

Comment: you mean, I've got to write the whole object structure again? i.e. `var json = { foo: data.foo.bar, id: data.baz, x: data.x, y: data.y }` ?

Comment: couldn't you just make a `json_copy` var and update that one, you then have two different instances you can work with independently

Comment: How do you expect to modify a copy of the object without making a copy?

Comment: @BenjaminM:  since you're staying in the JSON subset, copy=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orig)) works...

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`angular.extend()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) or [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to copy only the original object's own properties. i.e. shallow copy

```
var json = angular.extend({}, data);
json.foo = data.foo.bar;
json.id = data.baz;
delete json.baz;
```

or

```
var json = angular.extend({}, data, {
  foo: data.foo.bar,
  id: data.baz
});
delete json.baz;
```

Note that the following won't work because `data`'s `foo` will overwrite the first argument object's `foo`.

```
var json = angular.extend({
  foo: data.foo.bar,
  id: data.baz
}, data);
delete json.baz;
```